# Write the value of a variable as well as a string to a text file using StreamWriter

Tags: string, c++-cli, external, delimiter, streamwriter

I've written a program which allows the user to input information and store them in a few variables and then output the value of said variables to a text file using StreamWriter. The code is below:

```
questionWriter -> Write (question, "|");
questionWriter -> Write (answerA, "|");
questionWriter -> Write (answerB, "|");
questionWriter -> Write (answerC, "|");
questionWriter -> Write (answerD, "|");
questionWriter -> Write (correctAnswer, "|");
```

Now here's the issue. I also want to export a | as well in front of each variable as a delimiter, as I want another program to read these variables and every time it finds a | it knows that another variable is coming up. What happens however is that when I go to the text file, nothing is present. I believe it may be a syntax error but I can't find the issue. The strange thing is that if I do not include the "|", the variables are exported perfectly, just with no spaces. Can any of you notice a mistake or perhaps a better way of accomplishing what I am attempting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See documentation on [StreamWriter::Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.write(v=vs.110).aspx), which shows that Write() with only parameter writes the parameter to the stream, but when using two (or more) parameters you change into a variation of the [String.Format()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be(v=vs.110).aspx)-function, where you need to look at the [format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx) specification especially.

In other words, you could try either of the following to accomplish your goal:

```
// depreceated as it unclear to read, but it does make all arguments into one object
questionWriter->Write(question + "|" + answerA + "|" ... ); 

// my preferred variant
questionWriter->Write("{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}|{4}|{5}|",
                      question, answerA, answerB, answerC, answerD, correctAnswer);
```

Hope this helps!